# EF6 add migration fails - Access to the path 'C\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MyContext.edmx' is denied

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I've added new DbSet to my context and tried to run Add-Migration, but it fails with weird error:

> Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\MyContext.edmx' is denied.

Of course, the file does not exist in that directory. What can cause this problem?

This is not my first migration, but I have no idea what caused the path to change or how to revert it to previous value.

Comment: Somehow the "base path" of the utility has been set as c:\Windows\System32. 
How exactly are you running this ? If from Visual Studio, do you start it as administrator ? which version are you using ?

Comment: From inside VS2017, Package Manager Console with proper project selected

Comment: I think you are running from wrong path

Comment: I can remember it somehow happened to me, but the cause was "obvious", in the sense that I have not had the solution opened. In your case the solution related to the project is opened, right ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I restarted the whole computer- didn't help.

But, inspired by @Pac0 comment, I used Nuget Package Manager to update one of the packages hoping it would fix the base path. Also, that particular project runs in admin mode, so I started VS in admin mode also.

After that, the path is correct and the tool works.